# Requirements for (not-quite-) constexpr template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, constexpr

Both GCC (5.3.0) and Clang (3.8.0) agree that this is valid code:

```
constexpr std::integral_constant<size_t, 0> n{};
std::get<n>(std::make_tuple(123));
```

However, they disagree on this:

```
std::integral_constant<size_t, 0> n;
std::get<n>(std::make_tuple(123));
```

Clang is ok with it, but GCC reports "the value of 'n' is not usable in a constant expression" / "'n' was not declared 'constexpr'".

Whose behaviour matches the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang is right, although it ultimately depends on your library implementation. The standard does not per se disallow calling a `constexpr` function for a non-`const`(`expr`) object in constant expressions; only usage of that object's members would be a problem (see [[expr.const]/(2.7.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2)). Since the conversion operator most certainly simply returns `0`, it's probably a GCC bug (also suggestive when considering the error message).